# How to avail all of the disk space in Google Cloud VM Instance?

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have allocated 500GB for an instance. When I run the command `df -H`, this is what I get:
[image: Image: Result of df -H]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, I needed to reboot the instance for new settings: which was Disk space to 500GB from 100GB.